# Simplest table conversion in Org-mode hangs emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I got started with emacs mainly to try out org-mode, so I'm new with both. I can create tables from scratch (easily!). However, when I try to select, say

```
one,two,three
```

and convert it with `C-c |` emacs crashes! What am I doing wrong? I need to mark the text without a mouse, as I'm using a VPS to try this out.

Thanks!

Edit: I should add that I'm still within my first 24 hours using Emacs, ever! Just in case, I'm trying to select the text by pressing `C-<SPC>` at one end, moving the cursor to the other end, and then pressing `C-c |`. But then the echo area shows precisely `C-c |`, and nothing happens.

Second edit: It should not come as a surprise that running `top` shows the emacs process taking up 99.3% of the CPU resources. Very puzzling...

Comment: Works as expected here. What system and what version of Emacs are you using? Have you made any customizations? If so, have you tried it with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Emacs 23.4, the one I got by running `apt-get install emacs` in my VPS. No customizations whatsoever. Using the `-Q` flag didn't help. Maybe it has something to do with my Spanish keyboard? The echo area does show `C-c |`, but nothing happens. Must I then press `<RET>`? I'll edit the question to clarify how I'm selecting the text. Thanks again.

Comment: I suggest to build yourself an emacs from source. It takes about 10min.

Comment: Maybe it's indeed some sort of confusion related to keyboard. Can you do `C-h k` and then `C-c |` to see if this key combination is indeed bound to `org-table-create-or-convert-from-region`?

Comment: Thanks, wvxvw. I ran your command and got the following: "C-c | runs the command org-table-create-or-convert-from-region, which
is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function.

It is bound to C-c |.

[Arg list not available until function definition is loaded.]

Documentation will be available after `org-table.el' is loaded." My hunch is that I'm not selecting a region properly, although I have tried basic killing and yanking.

Comment: Well, all functions which operate on regions can also be called with two arguments `begin` and `end`, which are values of the point at the beginning and end of selection. So here's what you can do to make sure the function works w/o selecting. Move the point to the start of the line, press `C-x =` - this will show the position in the minibuffer. Do the same for the end of selection. Then do `M-: (org-table-create-or-convert-from-region start end)` (substitute start and end where appropriate).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your instructions led me to try something as simple as ssh instead of my beloved mosh... and now it worked! Any thoughts as to why this may happen? I guess it's high time to set up a local virtual machine in my computer, as cygwin doesn't even launch Emacs. Thanks again! (Feel feel to answer... I don't like to answer my own questions.)

Comment: Well, I never even heard of mosh before ;) It really hard to guess why would it happen... but if you really want to find out, I'd try to build Emacs including the debug info, then start it from GDB and try to do the same thing as you did. But this is really a lot of trouble, esp. so I wouldn't even know where to look at (if it just hangs, instead of erroring).

Comment: Not to worry, and in any event I finally got Emacs running locally under Cygwin, so it's all good. As a side note, I can't believe I took so long to try Emacs...